# Same code but getting different result

Tags: c#, datetime, nodatime

When I use below code I am getting different result on my developer pc and my remote server.

```
string _QsDateTime = "12.11.2016 21:30";
var _CountryZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["TUR"];
var _DatePattern = LocalDateTimePattern.CreateWithCurrentCulture("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
var _LocalTime = _DatePattern.Parse(_QsDateTime).Value;
var _LocalTime2TargetZoneTime = _LocalTime.InZoneStrictly(_CountryZone);
var _TargetZone2Utc = _LocalTime2TargetZoneTime.WithZone(DateTimeZone.Utc).ToDateTimeUtc();
_QsDateTime = _TargetZone2Utc.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Developer PC result is: "**2016-11-12** 19:30:00"
Remote server result is: "**2016-12-11** 19:30:00"

Remote server specs is Windows 2012 server English Developer PC specs is Windows 7 Turkish but both of them regional date time setting are same.

Why I am getting different result?

Comment: Not very familiar with NodaTime but the `CreateWithCurrentCulture()` call looks suspicious to me. Obviously in some cultures day comes first and in other months come first. You're parsing a `string` that has a different meaning in different cultures using the `CurrentCulture` and expect the same result... that's not possible. What exactly are you trying to achieve? The code looks prone to bugs.

Comment: I am trying to get same result. Like this  "2016-11-12 19:30:00"

Comment: I get that. You need to understand that on the remote PC the string `12.11.2016 21:30` means `December, 11th 2016 19:30:00` and on your PC it means `November 12th 2016 19:30:30`. You cannot use `CurrentCulture`. Specify the `Culture` that your string is **supposed to be**.

Comment: It should be `Europe/Istanbul` in my opinion.

Comment: That code should be giving you an exception such as "Unhandled Exception: NodaTime.TimeZones.DateTimeZoneNotFoundException: Time zone TUR is unknown to source TZDB: 2016c (mapping: 12348)". Please provide a real [mcve].

Comment: The pattern you've shown will never parse the value you've specified, either...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not *too much* familiar with Noda Time but I have a few things to say:

1. `DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb` does *not* have a time zone identifier as `TUR` as far as I know, you should use [`Europe/Istanbul`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Istanbul) instead.
2. When you create a `LocalDateTimePattern` with `CreateWithCurrentCulture` method, it uses **current** culture settings and these are different in your both server. Be careful about that.
3. [`LocalDateTimePattern.Parse`](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/api/html/M_NodaTime_Text_LocalDateTimePattern_Parse.htm) method use the rules of the current pattern. Your string is `12.11.2016 21:30` but your pattern is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. You see my point, don't you?
4. If you really get different results in your servers, you shouldn't blame your last line since both `en-US` and `tr-TR` cultures uses `GregorianCalendar` as a `Calendar` property and that doesn't effect the result. You might wanna check `LocalDateTimePattern.Parse` method line instead.

For example;

```
using System;
using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.Text;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string _QsDateTime = "12.11.2016 21:30";
        var _CountryZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Europe/Istanbul"];
        var _DatePattern = LocalDateTimePattern.CreateWithCurrentCulture("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
        var _LocalTime = _DatePattern.Parse(_QsDateTime).Value;
        var _LocalTime2TargetZoneTime = _LocalTime.InZoneStrictly(_CountryZone);
        var _TargetZone2Utc = _LocalTime2TargetZoneTime.WithZone(DateTimeZone.Utc).ToDateTimeUtc();
        _QsDateTime = _TargetZone2Utc.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Console.WriteLine(_QsDateTime);
    }
}
```

generates

```
2016-11-12 19:30:00
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/57X1Pv)</kbd>.